# InAppPurchase from another nsobject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

i built an in app purchase and it work fine.
then i created a new objective c class and put all the coding for in app purchase in the new class.
ok, now i want to call the in app purchase from my main view controller. how is it possible? thanks

*viewcontroller.m*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    InAppPurchaseManager *IAPmanager = [[InAppPurchaseManager alloc]init];
    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
        {
            //sets payment observer to class.
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

            //initializes products array.
            products = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [IAPmanager loadStore];

        }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"failed");
            }

}
```

*InAppPurchaseManager.m*

```
-(void)loadStore
{
    //restarts any purchases if they were interupted last time the was open
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addTransactionObserver:self];
    //get the product description
    ViewController *viewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [viewcontroller requestProductData];
}
//request product
-(void)requestProductData
{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.company.myApp.App1",nil ];
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
    NSLog(@"product request start");

}
```

it stopped running before this

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    myproducts = response.products;
    for(proUpgradeProduct in myproducts)
    {
        //debug log.
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }
    // invalid purchase
    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];

    NSLog(@"receive respond");
}
```

Comment: i did try to call all the methods manually,like request product data and it work great.but when it came to something store kit responsible like - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response, it never call by itself after request product start

Answer (score 0):

Call This method from any class you want-

-(IBAction) purchase:(id)sender
{

InAppPurchaseManager *inapp = [[InAppPurchaseManager alloc] init];

[inapp loadStore];

```
if ([inapp canMakePurchases]) {
    [inapp purchaseProUpgrade];
```

}
}

Comment: i called load store and it stopped before request didReceiveResponse.

Comment: the word stop you mean didnt gone into that method?

Comment: yup, i added some code to my post.you can see it didn't log"receive respond"

Comment: Have you made changes in the itunes account,have you set Product-id in Section -Manage InApp Purchases?

Comment: yes,i was success to make purchases until i pull everything from main view controller into another class.i also wonder i should create a nsobject or uiview for the class?would that affect anything? i'm kinda fresh in IOS

Comment: Is your ProductId on itunes account is this "com.company.myApp.App1"